# Get the only element in a Set

Tags: java, iterator, set

I need to know the "best" and safest way to get a value held within a Set if there is only one entry.  `methodToGetValues()` is used extensively to read config files and return a list of values given a specific key, in this case `"enabled"`.  For the `enabled` key, there should only be one entry returned in the Set, obviously `"true"` or `"false"` but, mistakes happen.  I have the following which seems a little convoluted:

```
Set<String> enabled = methodToGetValues("enabled");

if (!enabled.isEmpty() && enabled.size() < 2 && "true".equals(enabled.iterator().next())) {
    ...
}
```

Can anyone suggest a simpler yet still robust way of checking this?

Comment: Why do you have a set with only one element? I'm just wondering because I feel like this could be an XY problem.

Comment: For other keys, the values returned are multiple when reading the config files, so the Set will have more elements.

Comment: why not write a new methodToGetValue for this type of value?

Comment: What you have looks good, though if you can use third-party libraries Guava's `Iterables.getOnlyElement` is pretty much custom designed for this use case.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That was exactly what I was after, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question asks to get something from the Set. But your example just needs a check.

If you know what to expect in the Set, this works fine.

```
    if (enabled != null && enabled.size() == 1 && enabled.contains("true")) {
        ...
    }
```

Otherwise, if you just want to get the element but don't know what it is, the iterator you suggested works fine.

```
    String getOnlyElement(Set<String> enabled, String default) {
        return (enabled == null || enabled.size() != 1) ? default : enabled.iterator().next();
    }
```

I like having null checks but it depends on what methodToGetValues returns.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of what the use case is that would drive using a `Set<String>` for this data but here is an option:

```
// check size = 1 over two checks,  use contains rather than grabbing an iterator
if (set.size() == 1 && set.contains("true")) {
    ...    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Set<String> getValues(final String key){
    .....
}

public String getValue(final String key) {
    final Set<String> values = getValues(key);
    if (values == null || values.size() != 1) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid configuration for give key :" + key);
    }

    return values.iterator().next();
}

public Boolean getValueAsBoolean(final String key) {
    return Boolean.valueOf(getValue(key));
}
```

You can modify method to have accept argument to return default value when keys are not found. You can add different methods to return specific type object like inte, boolean, this way code looks cleaner